# Email Bot - Avoiding infinite loops

Tags: algorithm, email, throttling

I'm writing an email bot and think I could run into infinite loops due to out-of-office replies. Curious if you know any battle-tested solutions here.

Scenario:

- Imagine you are programming an email bot that receives an email, processes it, and sends a reply back.
- Now imaging the user who sends the email has an automatic out-of-office (OOO) reply configured in their clients.

  - Assume it's a dumb client, that always auto-responds with no logic around knowing if a particular email has already been notified of their OOO status.

How would you prevent infinite loops?

- (where the user emails the bot, the bot responds, the OOO is fired, the bot responds to the OOO, another OOO is fired, etc.)

Assume you can't just configure a different reply-to email because in the normal use case, you'd want to have the ability to respond to a response.

Options:

- Are there libraries to reliably detect an OOO and ignore? Given it's multilingual, in many formats, from many email clients that seems improbable.
- Would you implement some kind of history per user and if you see the first X characters from the same person Y times in a row, you'd ignore their message? Seems imprecise and could accidentally block emails with a similar yet verbose preamble.
- Would you implement some kind of throttling? Seems like you can catch very fast auto-replies, but not the slow kind that's replying once per hour.

What are other solutions you've seen implemented in practice to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 2):

A common solution is to add a header to messages you send, and not respond if you see this header.

Procmail conventionally uses `X-Loop:` for this.

```
:0
* ! ^X-Loop: youraddress@example\.com
| formail -I "X-Loop: youraddress@example.com" etc etc
```

You might also want to examine standard headers, and avoid responding to messages with e.g. an `Auto-Submitted:` header etc.

Comment: For your entertainment, perhaps see also https://www.iki.fi/era/mail/autoresponder-faq

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a "bucket" for each e-mail address, and use [Token Bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) algorithm to throttle activity. If you will see "ping-ping", there is lot of messages, received from specific e-mail address during a short timeframe, and when there is too many e-mails from client - you will stop answering.